# Ios charts zoom back out after double tap

Tags: ios, swift, zooming, ios-charts

Hi i am new to iOS charts.

[iOS-Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

I am using double tap to zoom into my LineChart, but cannot find a way to zoom back out.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to intercept the double tap and save my state and restore it later?

I am using Charts 3.0.1 and Swift 3.0.2.

Thanks.

Comment: is this problem is still there ? if yes let me know you want it back as normal state means on 0 scale or something else ?

Comment: Yes it is still a problem. What I meant was that I'd like to be able to doubletap to zoom in (which it does), then have a way (single or another double tao) to zoom back out to the scale it was before my zoom in. Right now if I doubletap a second time, it zooms in even further.

Comment: so for that you have to add one button on screen which will undo ur zoom for that you have to call xAxis & yAxis reset.

Comment: How do we reset the xAxis & yAxis? In swift 3 or 4

Answer (score 5):

This is how you zoom out in `Charts`

```
chartView.fitScreen()
```

Since [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) is analogy to [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), huge part of its documentation, wiki and Q&A applies to both libraries.

Answer (score 2):

This is how we did it. We put this line of code when a button was tapped to reset the zoom.

```
self.lineChartView.zoomToCenter(scaleX: 0, scaleY: 0)
```

If you want, you can also put in a plus and minus button and zoom in/out accordingly. You can get the current scale by using this line of code `self.lineChartView.scaleX` or `self.lineChartView.scaleY` and then add/subtract a fixed amount every time the zoom in/out button is tapped.